# Where are anki deck files stored

Tags: file, directory, anki

Once I import a file, and I corrupt it (having anki synchronisation turned off) the deck is still fully functional. So where is a copy of the imported file stored? What folder in macos or windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [relevant section of the manual](https://docs.ankiweb.net/files.html#file-locations), all Anki's files are stored at the following places:

- Windows: `%APPDATA\Anki2`
- MacOS: `~/Library/ApplicationSupport/Anki2`

However, there are some gotchas. If you need more details, see the link.

Besides that, beware that decks are not stored as individual files: the whole Anki collection is a single database, so you can't copy decks around. However, you can still export decks from within Anki.